# Unable to fix error in Cyanogenmod build compilation with Jack

Tags: android, android-source, cyanogenmod

I'm having problems with building CyanogenMod 13 even after following all instructions to the T from this site: https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_serrano3gxx. Here's the error:

> Building with Jack:
>   /home/norandomtechie/android/system/out/target/common/obj
>   /JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v8-renderscript_intermediates/classes.jack
>   java.lang.AssertionError at
>   com.android.sched.scheduler.MultiWorkersScheduleInstance.process
>   (MultiWorkersScheduleInstance.java:490)  at
>   com.android.jack.Jack.run(Jack.java:597)  at
>   com.android.jack.Jack.checkAndRun(Jack.java:367)  at
>   com.android.jack.CommandLine.runJack(CommandLine.java:66)  at
>   com.android.jack.server.ServerTaskInsideVm.run(ServerTaskInsideVm.java:94)
>   at
>   com.android.jack.server.JackSimpleServer$JackRun.handle(JackSimpleServer.java:427)
>   at
>   com.android.jack.server.JackSimpleServer$JackRouter.handle(JackSimpleServer.java:311)
>   at
>   org.simpleframework.http.core.RequestDispatcher.dispatch(RequestDispatcher.java:121)
>   at
>   org.simpleframework.http.core.RequestDispatcher.run(RequestDispatcher.java:103)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Internal compiler error (version 1.1-mr2 'Brest' (175100
>   000a2f91edbe638090dc577801ba49592229fd8b)).  Warning: This may have
>   produced partial or corrupted output.  Building with Jack:
>   /home/norandomtechie/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES
>   /android-support-v7-recyclerview-res_intermediates/classes.jack
>   build/core/java.mk:643:  recipe for target
>   '/home/norandomtechie/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES
>   /framework_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex' failed  make: ***
>   [/home/norandomtechie/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES
>   /framework_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex] Error 41  make: ***
>   Waiting for unfinished jobs....  make: Leaving directory
>   '/home/norandomtechie/android/system'

This happens every time I start the build. I've synced the source code every time before running a compilation, but it doesn't help. My guess is that it's a compiler error in Jack, which I have no idea how to fix. How should I proceed to fix this error? It's my first time doing this, with little experience in Java. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it could be because `~/.jack` has an incorrect permission you can fix it with

```
chmod 777 ~/.jack
```

as was suggested here: https://gist.github.com/nickwph/507064e2e3f347a92505

but what fixed for me was **allocating more memory.**